# Having Problems With Updating Composer

Tags: symfony, composer-php, vagrant

I am running into some problems trying to update composer, after trying to add php-imap.

I am getting this error:

> Plugin initialization failed (include(/var/www/vendor/composer/package-versions-deprecated/src/PackageVersions/Installer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory), uninstalling plugin
>
> - Removing composer/package-versions-deprecated (1.10.99)
>   Install of composer/package-versions-deprecated failed
>
> [RuntimeException]
> Could not delete /var/www/vendor/composer/package-versions-deprecated/src:
>
> the file (/var/www/vendor/composer/package-versions-deprecated/src/PackageVersions/Installer.php) does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer cannot delete the `/var/www/vendor/composer/package-versions-deprecated/src` directory. I guess current user cannot write/delete directory in `/var/www`

**Option 1 (recommended)**
You can (you have to) fix the right to this directory and verify that current connected user has enough privilege to do it.

**Option 2**
You can install application locally (in a directory where current user have all privileges,
Launch composer
Move via root the application to the /var/www directory
Chown files to the good user. (www:data ?)

**Option 3 (not recommended)**
You can delete this directory manually via root. But I'm sure you will encountered a lot of other problems.

Comment: I'm getting this error running on Windows 10 with a fresh install of Vagrant on VirtualBox. How would I fix this error in this environment?

Comment: by fixing security in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

clear composer's cache:

```
rm -rf ~/.composer/cache
```